# Creating a child process on Unix systems?

Tags: c, unix, parent-child, child-process

I'm trying to create a child process in another process. I am writing both the programs in C language. First I write a dummy process which will be the child process. What it is doing is only to write a string on the screen. It works well on its own. Then I write another program which will be the parent process. However, I can't make it happen. I'm trying to use fork and execl functions together, but I fail. I also want the child process does not terminate until the parent process terminates.

How should I write the parent process?

Thanks.

Here is the code for the child process:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  while(1) {
    printf("*");
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

And here is the parent process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  if (fork()) {
    while(1) {
      printf("-\n");
      sleep(5);
    }
  } else {
    execl("./", "dummy", (char *)0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You say you "fail", but you haven't shown any code. How do you expect us to tell where you are doing wrong? Also, the parent process manages the child process, so the child process ALWAYS finishes BEFORE the parent process. If the parent process dies first, the grand-parent adopts the child (up to /sbin/init, the great-grand-parent of all processes, which should never die).

Comment: Okay, sorry I edited my question with the code.

Comment: Add a perror("execl") after your execl statement and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fork() system call may return three different statuses: failure (<0), parent process (>0) or child process (==0). You must test the return value properly.

```
int pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) {
  /* handle error */
  perror("fork");
  exit(1);
} else if (pid > 0) {
  /* parent code */
} else {
  /* child code */
}
```

Your execl() system call is wrong. The first argument is the path to the program you want to execute, "./" is not valid, it should be something like "./dummy" at least. The next argument is by convention the command name (argv[0] in the executed program), which may be a repetition of the first argument. So:

```
execl("./dummy", "dummy", NULL);
```

Also, note that the `printf("*")` statement in the child program will probably buffer and you won't see anything on the terminal. You must either add a "\n" to the end or call `fflush(stdout)` to flush the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

Basic use of fork in C

```
int PID = fork();

if( PID < 0 ) {
    //fail
    return PID;
}
else if( !PID ) {
    //child process
    return exec( prog, args );
} 
else {
    //parent process
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the parent process WILL exit, even if some of its children / descendants are still alive. If the parent wants to wait for them, it has to do so deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force the child process to "not terminate" when it's done (you'll still be able in the parent to `wait` for it to get info on how it terminated, but that's about it). Apart from that, any of the many examples of `fork`/`exec` on the web, such as [this one](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html), should work -- why don't you try it and see if it performs as you wish (in which case you'll just need to change whatever you were doing differently in your own attempt).  If it doesn't work as desired (except for the impossibility per the first sentence in this A;-), please edit your to add copious detail about how the code behaves differently than you expect it to.

Comment: You can put a loop in the child process after it has finished its work but before it exits, that waits for the parent to die (eg. by waiting for `EOF` on a pipe connected to the parent).

Comment: If you control the child process's source code, never have any error in it, _and_ can somehow guarantee it won't receive unwelcome signals, yes, but those can be pretty hard things to guarantee.